# Service created by express (node js) accessible by using localhost, but not accessible when using ip address

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, networking, https

I created a simple https web service using an express framework (node js)

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(443, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('server running .....')
})



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello HTTPS!')
})
```

Now when accessing from the same system where I created this web service, 
I could access the service if I use "localhost", but I cannot access it if I use the same system IP address.

The client used: Chrome browser.

```
https://localhost/
Output: Hello HTTPS!

https://<my_system_ip> 
This site cannot be reached.
```

Is this expected result? Service on 443 port is not accessible with IP address?
Anything I need to correct the way I am creating the service in express?

If I create the service with anyother port , it works.

```
https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('server running .....')
})

https://localhost:3000
Output: Hello HTTPS!

https://<my_system_ip>:3000
Output: Hello HTTPS!
```

Comment: `IP address` which IP? public IP?

Comment: Private IP, the IPv4 address assigned to that host where the service is running.

Comment: If you create an HTTP service rather than HTTPS, does it work for `http://<my_system_ip>`?

Comment: @shaochuancs : No, it works with only with localhost even for http (port 80)